# Multiple methods named 'setCornerRadius:' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I get this error when i try to set the corner radius of a segment

```
[[self.daysSegment.subviews objectAtIndex:cnt] setCornerRadius:0];
```

> Multiple methods named 'setCornerRadius:' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
[[(UIView*)[self.daysSegment.subviews objectAtIndex:cnt] layer] setCornerRadius:0];
```

**Edit**

I will suggest you to break above code. It will make debugging much easier.

```
UIView  *view  = [self.daysSegment.subviews objectAtIndex:cnt];
CALayer *layer = [view layer];
layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should be able to set the border width of the segment the same way right? `layer.borderWidth = 0.0;` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Is it custom segment or ios default? Ios default segment's corner radius might not work. I can't say anything now. I have to try first.

Comment: IOS default segment i am adding the segments dynamically but at each addition i change the borderwidth. on a different page this code worked
`NSArray *array = [self.segment subviews];`
        `[[array objectAtIndex:0] setBorderWidth:0];`
        `[[array objectAtIndex:0] setCornerRadius:0];`

but its giving a runtime exception on this i can't figure out why. Am very new to IOS and Objective-C

Comment: sorry just figured out that the above way(previous comment) didn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
[[self.daysSegment.subviews objectAtIndex:cnt].layer setCornerRadius:0];
```

cornerRadius apply on view layer

Comment: it gives the error `Property 'layer' not found on object of type 'id'`

Comment: you need to convert 'id' to view, but strange i tried i my project and works

Comment: [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0].layer setCornerRadius:12]; this my example

Answer (score 0):

```
((UIView*)[self.daysSegment.subviews objectAtIndex:cnt]).layer.cornerRadius = 0
```